# Defining a univariate regression

Tags: regression, definition, multivariate-regression, univariate

Does the following qualify as a univariate regression?

$$y=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\epsilon$$

I fully comprehend the implications of adding regressors and need no background information - a "yes" or "no" will do :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. "Multivariate" and "univariate", when they're used to describe models, refer to the number of dependent variables, not the number of independent variables. A multivariate linear regression model, for example, predicts several different variables, and the residuals are multivariate normal rather than univariate normal. See, for example, the Wikipedia article ["Linear regression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression):

> For more than one explanatory variable, the process is called *multiple linear regression.* (This term should be distinguished from *multivariate linear regression*, where multiple correlated dependent variables are predicted, rather than a single scalar variable.)

Hence, your model is a multiple linear regression model, but also a univariate linear regression model.

Comment: +1 to make you over 5k :-) Congratulations. You might want in addition to comment if it is *multiple* regression or not.

Comment: Good idea. It is done.